# Glassdoor API login not working with Python, response 403 Bots not allowed

Tags: python

Unfortunately I get the error: HTTP Status 403 - Bots not allowed while using the following Python code.

```
import requests

URL = 'http://api.glassdoor.com/api/api.htm?v=1&format=json&t.p={PartnerID}&t.k={Key}&action=employers&q=pharmaceuticals&userip={IP_address}&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0'

response = requests.get(URL)

print(response)
```

The URL does work when I try it from my browser. What can I do to make it work from a code?

**Update: SOLVED.**

Apologies for not posting the question in the right way (I am new at SO).

Comment: Is it working in your browser ? you can also use an app such as Postman to test your request. If the request works, it is indeed a python issue. 403 means usually a problem in your credentials, so your password might be wrong, or improperly inserted by python.

Comment: According to the api, it should also return JSON explaining what is wrong. So what is the text you get back together with the 403?

Comment: @J.Meijers the response is: Bots not allowed, Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454571/python-glassdoor-api?rq=1), you need to include a header field (note that this example uses urllib2 rather than requests):

```
import urllib2, sys
url = "http://api.glassdoor.com/api/api.htm?t.p=yourID&t.k=yourkey&userip=8.28.178.133&useragent=Mozilla&format=json&v=1&action=employers&q="
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(url,headers=hdr)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

with the `requests` module, it's probably:

```
import requests

URL = 'http://api.glassdoor.com/api/api.htm?v=1&format=json&t.p={PartnerID}&t.k={Key}&action=employers&q=pharmaceuticals&userip={IP_address}&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0'

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response)
```